# Does hbase scan operation read rows which were created after it started

Tags: hbase

I think that to avoid confusion, hbase scan should *not* scan the rows which are created after it has already started execution. But I couldn't find any documentation stating this explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a scenario where your row keys starts with any letter from a to z. You have million number of rows in a given table. You must have already know HBase sorts rows lexicographically. Assume you start to scan whole table, consider your scan pointer is at row key starts with 'e'. Now consider at the same moment you inserted two entries with row key 'bbbbb' and 'hhhh'. If you analyse your resultset, you will get row with rowKey 'hhhh'. You will not get row with rowKey 'bbbbb'. I have actually checked this by scanning a table with very large amount of data and inserting records in between.